# Submit Form (PHP/Javascript) every 15 minutes

Tags: javascript, php, forms, submit, casperjs

Look into several parts on the web but found something that will help me.

I have a form, which automate the best I could with **PHP and Javascript** (JS generates a random number and concatenate into one of the form fields)

Now all I have to do is "press" the send button.
I occupy **CasperJS** (console) to send an instruction to make the process (Enter the page - Press Button - Wait results - Repeat manually)

But I want to automate with any of these (cron job, curl, casperJS) and **send it every 15 minutes** (I forget to write the instruction and send it, so I want to automate this).

The FORM is in a **basic shared server** with Apache / MySql.

I would send you the link but is private.

Any idea how you could do it.

Comment: You've done an excellent job of sharing what you have without showing what you have

Comment: Cron would be what you're looking for, since it's a server-side method. Client-side demands that the browser be open in order to execute at different time intervals.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yes but I can not make it work, it is perhaps because the server does not accept many things, or maybe see the JS.

Comment: It depends. Does your server support/offer cron? If you're on a free hosted site, many don't offer cron.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yes, my server have support. I found a great tutorial but is only for server who support JS/NodeJS.

Comment: You should be able to run the file then. However, it needs to be `.php` in order to work properly.

Comment: Ok, I will seek more thoroughly in Crob jobs, that's the most logical way.
Everything looks very advanced, I've never used. Thanks @Fred-ii-

Comment: You're welcome. I too had some difficulties with cron at first, but when you get the hang of it, you will see that it will become clearer and easier as you go. Find tutorials on the subject and continue reading the ones that you understand. Some are not well explained. *Cheers*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can achieve what you need with casperjs alone by using the js setinterval and a neat little feature in most linux boxes, called screen. In ubuntu you would install it like so:

```
sudo apt-get install screen
```

Now in order to use it:

1. Create a new file with .js extension to be run with casperjs.
   here Is an sample code you could try:

   ```
   casper.start('http://myurl.com/myform.php', function() {
       setinterval(function(){
           // click the submit button
           casper.waitForSelector("your buttonselector")
                 .thenClick("yourbuttonselector");
           console.log('button pressed.');
      },15*60*1000);//the time in miliseconds
   }).run(function(){/* this prevents exiting*/});
   ```
2. save the script above as a file eg:myfile.js
3. Write into the console screen and press enter enter.
4. Run the script: `casperjs myscript.js`
5. at this point the program will run forever. you can close the console or Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> in order to minimize the screen.
6. in order to see and reopen write `screen -x`

Comment: I have a little problem:
In my line::: this.click('#botonenviar');
I get this: TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'this.click('input.submit')')

Comment: @CrlsPerez I have edited the part with this.click with n it: casper.waitForSelector("#somethingelse1").thenClick("#somethingelse1"); please try and let me know.